# Python cleanest way to send data to a generator in a loop

Tags: python, generator

Let's say I have a generator which accepts sent values, the following being an example:

```
def echo_generator():
    data = None
    for i in range(10):
        data = yield data
```

And I want to send data to it in a loop:

```
data = None
gen = echo_generator()
i = 0
while True:
    try:
        x = gen.send(data)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    print(x)
    if i < 5:
        data = 'smaller'
    else:
        data = 'larger'
    i += 1
```

Is there a way of shortening this code? It appears rather convoluted to me. Ideally I want to use `enumerate` to get `i` coupled with a for loop, something like the following:

```
data = None
gen = echo_generator()
for i, x in enumerate( ... gen.send(data) ... ):
    print(x)
    if i < 5:
        data = 'smaller'
    else:
        data = 'larger'
```

but I don't see a way of doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you cannot modify the generator, you can pass itertools.count(), which is an infinite sequence.

```
import itertools

data = None
gen = echo_generator()
for i, x in enumerate(gen.send(data) for a in itertools.count()):
    print(x)
    if i < 5:
        data = 'smaller'
    else:
        data = 'larger'
```

It works, but only because of a quirk. Consider:

```
[gen.send(data) for a in itertools.count()]
```

This will raise `StopIteration`, because `gen.send` raises it, and nothing catches it.

But exceptions bubble up when they are not catched, and when it raises inside the `enumerate` function in the loop, the `enumerate` function didn't catch it, and so it bubbles up to the for loop, which takes it to mean that the `enumerate` iterator is finished.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't modify the generator. Question is about usage of a defined generator.

Comment: It's still a good answer though. Your OP should have included that constraint, and even with that constraint it might be good to leave this (as in, not down voted and potentially also not up voted) to document a good idea for others not facing that constraint.

Comment: Do you know the limit of iterations required inside of the generator, in this case the value 10? If so, you could use this solution anyway, and potentially just pass such a huge number of possible iterations to `enumerate` that you are guaranteed to exhaust the inner generator first.

Comment: @EMS No, it's a rather complicated generator function, I just gave a simple example to be more relevant to the question, if that helps.

Comment: @EMS The question isn't about modifying the generator, and the constraint is really a clarification, the question title clearly expresses my intent, to send data to the generator not to re-write it. I've edited my question again, hope it's clearer now.

Comment: @simonzack I've edited my answer to accomodate the additional constraint.

Comment: @parchment That's a really weird way to make this work, good thinking :)